# Allowing internal address to be accessed via wireguard vpn

Tags: raspberry-pi, vpn, wireguard

This question has been asked a few times and I've spent plenty of time on ChatGPT trying to figure it out.

I have three machines:

- RP zero that has Wireguard VPN and a Fluidd dashboard that can be accessed via 192.168.0.1
- Android phone that has Wireguard VPN and wants to access the RP's dashboard
- centOS VPS that works as a wireguard vpn.

The method is simple:

- Create a VPN server with Wireguard.
- Add the two devices to the conf of the server.
- Add the conf to each device.
- The RP should allow the local VPN ip of the phone in its conf.
- Port-forward the localip:80 to the 192.168.0.1

Issue:

- The phone cannot access the dashboard, because the request is not redirecting to 192.168.0.1.

Info:

- Pinging the 10.0.0.3 and 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2 works.
- Curling the RP returns "TIMED_OUT".
- The server enabled the access of port 51820.
- Both the phone and the RP are connected to the server and having a handshake & transfering down/up data.
- The RP can access its dashboard from within the device, and I can access it in the local network via another ip address.

If I misunderstood anything, please correct me.

`Server conf`

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
SaveConfig = true
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY

# Mobile Device Peer
[Peer]
PublicKey = MOBILE_PUBLIC_KEY
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.3/32

# Raspberry Pi Peer
[Peer]
PublicKey = RP_PUBLIC_KEY
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32
```

`RP conf`

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = RP_PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 10.0.0.2/24
DNS = 8.8.8.8

[Peer]
PublicKey = SERVER_PUB_KEY
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, 10.0.0.3/32, 10.0.0.1/32
Endpoint = SERVER_IP:51820
```

`Mobile conf`

[Interface]

```
PrivateKey = MOBILE_PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 10.0.0.3/24
DNS = 8.8.8.8

[Peer]
PublicKey = SERVER_PUB_KEY
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = SERVER_IP:51820
```

I've tried adding the port forwarding in the RP via

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wg0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:80`

But, it didn't work. Any help is appreciated. I have extremly low knowledge in this topic.

Comment: *I've spent plenty of time on ChatGPT trying to figure it out* that was your first mistake. What you can do is add 192.168.0.1/32 to the raspebrry pi peer allowed IP's on the server ... i.e `AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32,192.168.0.1/32`

Comment: I agree on the first point, It just saved me time from researching randomaly, but may added more issues. I currently have a reverse-proxy setup on my raspberry pi, If I add your suggestion, would it be possible to avoid the reverse-proxy design?

Comment: No clue, mate. First I've read of this so-called reverse-proxy design

Answer (score 0):

Well, not an actual answer. The issue was that I accessed "https" instead of "http".

I ended up creating a reverse proxy. I had to `"sudo tcpdump -i wg0-client` on the RP and ping the RP from the phone and I figured it out at the end.